# Loop through elements to find specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any number of elements can exist, with the following ID.

```
<div id="my-div-1">Title 1</div>
<div id="my-div-2">Title 2</div>
<div id="my-div-3">Title 3</div>
<div id="my-div-4">Title 4</div>
```

I would like to loop through those elements to see if the number at the end of the ID matches the number in a variable.

This is what I have so far thought it does not work:

```
var myNum = 3
var findNum = /[\d]+/;
var findElement = document.getElementById('my-div-' + findNum);
for(i=0; i<findElement; i++) {
    if (myNum = findNum) {
        console.log('Success! myNum = ' + myNum + 
                    ' and findNum = ' + findNum +
                    ' and findElement = ' + findElement);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Fail! myNum = ' + myNum + 
                    ' and findNum = ' + findNum + 
                    ' and findElement = ' + findElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: just do `var $element = $('#my-div-' + myNum)`

Comment: `if (myNum = findNum) {` <-- typo should be == and getElementByID only returns a single element, why the looping?

Comment: Why is your question tagged "jquery" when your code doesn't use any?

Comment: Maybe I do not need to loop.  There are 4 divs as an example, but I'd like to be able to target one even if I don't know how many divs exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the element directly like so:

**Non jQuery method:**

```
var myNum = 3;
var el = document.getElementById('my-div-' + myNum);
if (!el) {
    alert("Fail");
} else {
    alert("Success");
}
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/EtZxh/4/

**jQuery Method:**

If you want to use jQuery simply replace with the following:

```
var myNum = 5;
var el = $('#my-div-' + myNum);
if (el.size() == 0) {
    alert("Fail");
} else {
    alert("Success");
}
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/EtZxh/

Comment: Thanks for showing both Non jQuery and jQuery.  I misunderstood my problem and see now that I did not need a loop.  Thanks!

Comment: `getElementById` returns `null`, not `undefined` if it doesn't find the element. Either way, you don't need to explicitly check. Elements are truthy and `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, etc. are falsy.

Comment: @Blender - Good spot.  I've updated the example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery you could select it with the following:

```
var id = 4;
var $element = $("#my-div-" + id);
```

Where id is the variable that holds the number.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` doesn't return multiple elements. It returns only one:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('my-div-' + number);

if (elem) {
    // elem exists
}
```

And jQuery:

```
if ($('#my-div-' + number).length > 0) {
    // elem exists
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I would need a loop but this works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNum = 3;

$('div[id^="my-div-"]').each(function() {
    console.log("hello");
    if(myNum === parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('my-div-',''), 10)) {
      alert("found => " + $(this).attr('id'));
    } else {
      // do else
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6rwR/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in jQuery

```
var num = 3;
$("div[id^='my-div-']").each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    if(id.slice(-1) === num){
        alert("Success: " +id);
    }else{
        alert("Fail : " +id)
    }
});
```